# Observer vs. Registering callbacks

Tags: java, android, design-patterns

What are the pros and cons of using Observer versus just registering callbacks like:

```
worker.setOnJobIsDone(func);
```

Comment: Possible duplicate
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951276/callback-command-vs-eventlistener-observer-pattern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use function pointers, the object is completely unaware of its users; it just calls a function which allows for more flexibility (the users don't need to inherit anything, you can wire users of this object as you like).

Observer pattern requires you to define an interface. This is less flexible but more explicit.

I prefer the observer pattern strongly for the sake of readability; it is much easier to track workflow if you've never seen the code before. Also C++ syntax for passing member functions is kind of hard on the eyes.