# Is the observer object oriented design pattern just a form of implementing a callback?

Tags: oop, design-patterns, callback, observer-pattern

I was recently asked what is the difference between a callback and an observer in the Observer OO design pattern. My understanding is that callback is any executable code passed as an argument to a function which is called when a specific event happens. It may be implemented in different forms in different programming languages, such as function pointers, anonymous functions and observers/listeners in the object-oriented paradigm.

Developers *usually* implement callback registration synchronously with code execution and support only one callback, while observers/listeners callback registration is always asynchronous with code execution and multiple registration is supported.

However, I believe that those *usual* limitations of sync and cardinality in a callback are not inherent in its definition. Is that right?

Reference: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know that there is any official definition of *callback*. At least, it doesn't show up in [SE Vocab](https://pascal.computer.org/). It does show up on [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/824234/what-is-a-callback-function), but you can see some variation in the answers.

[Observer](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/observer-pattern/info) *does* have an official definition (GoF) and it is synonymous with publish/subscribe. Surely there are developers who define callback broadly enough to encompass pub/sub. Others draw a [distinction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8951276/callback-command-vs-eventlistener-observer-pattern) between the two.

You have to choose a callback definition. Then you will have an answer to this question.

By the way, regarding Wikipedia, there is extremely inaccurate and [misleading](https://twitter.com/ploeh/status/1175820397306109952) information on numerous design patterns there; so I would in no way consider it an official definition for anything technical.